# SimpleExoPlayerView is being shown in the background of simpleexoplayer

Tags: java, android, exoplayer

I've followed this tutorial and it seemed really odd to have exopalyerview in the background of the media player

like in this image [image: Image of video behind the mediaplayer in landscape mode]

The code i used for video

```
simpleExoPlayerView = (SimpleExoPlayerView) findViewById(R.id.player_view);
simpleExoPlayerView.requestFocus();
simpleExoPlayerView.setPlayer(player);


MediaSource mediaSource = new HlsMediaSource(Uri.parse("my_url"),
            mediaDataSourceFactory, mainHandler, null);

player.prepare(mediaSource);
player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
```

Comment: Can you edit your post and add your XML view file? I'm assuming the issue will be in the xml.

Comment: <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
            android:id="@+id/video_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

Comment: btw When i changed the height to fixed number, like 400dp, it worked fined but when i change it back to wrap_content/match_parent, it usually appears as above. been searching for a solution for a while can't find any